# How can I determine if a vector contains dates in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, datetime

Can you determine if a vector contains dates?

The vector I have has dates in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

I have seen the `isdatetime` function but it doesn't appear to work for me. I think it's because the vector is full of dates and not date times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`isdatetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isdatetime.html) doesn't actually check if something is a valid date, it only checks the type of the object to see if it is a [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) object. To see if you have a valid set of dates, you can try to create `datetime` objects from them and use the [`isnat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.isnat.html) function to see if they return `NaT` (i.e. "Not-a-Time"), indicating an invalid/undefined date format. Here's an example:

```
>> C = {'2019-01-01'; ...  % Cell array of date strings, last one invalid
        '2019-02-01'; ...
        '2019-03-01'; ...
        'blah'};
>> D = datetime(C)

D = 

  4×1 datetime array

   01-Jan-2019
   01-Feb-2019
   01-Mar-2019
   NaT        

>> isnat(D)

ans =

  4×1 logical array

   0
   0
   0
   1  % Fourth entry failed conversion
```